# PDFbox runs into error (how to calculate the position for non-simple fonts)

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, pdf, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox to fill up a form in my pdf file, application is able to show number of available fields on the form but it returns the following error

```
  Messages:     
     Error: Don't know how to calculate the position for non-simple fonts
     File:  org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDAppearance.java
     Line number:   616
```

**Code**

```
.....

while (fieldsIter.hasNext()) {
                PDField field = (PDField) fieldsIter.next();
                setField(pdf, field.getPartialName(), "My input");
                //setField(pdf, field.getFullyQualifiedName(), "My input");
}

 .....



 public void setField(PDDocument pdfDocument, String name, String value) throws 
 IOException {
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        PDField field = acroForm.getField(name);
        if (field != null) {
            field.setValue(value);
        } else {
            System.err.println("No field found with name:" + name);
        }

    }
```

Please let me know if you need any other part of the code.

Comment: Please also supply the PDF in question (or any sample PDF one can reproduce the issue with). Essentially the `PDAppearance` code in question only knows what to do if its `PDFont` actually is a `PDSimpleFont.` But currently `PDSimpleFont` is the only direct subclass of the abstract `PDFont.` Thus, the font parameter seems to be null. Your PDF now shall show whether no font is given by the PDF or the font given is broken, or whether there is some actual bug in PDFBox.

Comment: I've the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another PDF if that works means PDFBox is not compatible with the first pdf.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in pdfbox that occurs in various circumstances where it can't find the relevant font. The only workaround I've been able to find is just skipping the update appearance code that's run in `PDTextbox.setValue`. You can "force" the value to be updated by just doing:

```
COSString fieldValue = new COSString("Awesome field value");
textbox.getDictionary().setItem(COSName.V, fieldValue);
```

Presumably, in all but corner cases, the PDF viewer can handle rendering the font, and just setting the `V` item for the field should suffice. Subjectively the documents I've generated open fine in Acrobat and OS X preview.

Related issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1550

Edit to add: by default acrobat seems to create fields with a visible text area size of 0. For documents with this problem, you can get around this by adding `textbox.getDictionary().setItem(COSName.AP, null);` and hoping that the reader can handle rendering the appearance correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a PDF and I ended up solving it by editing the PDF form field (with Abobe Acrobat Pro) and setting an specific font.

The problem was that the problematic field didn't specify any font at all.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, the problem was that the PDF did not embed the font used.

Moreover the Preflight tools from Acrobat pro seemed unable to fix the PDF. I ended up recreating the PDF and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me by using Adobe Pro and merging to PDFs into one. After this the resulting PDF was not able to be used with PDFBox also the original PDFs worked. After a little research i found out, that the merge process destryos the font information. Just reset the fonts and it should work!

Best regards!